# Intellisense not working properly in Visual Studio Code with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am very new on PHP and Visual Studio Code.
I have installed all needed to start developing a basic website.
I have installed different extensions in VS Code but no one provide intellisense for operations such as

> mysqli_query, mysqli_fetch_array ...

In the other hand, it recognize:

> mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array

I have installed:

- PHP intellisense
- PHP debug
- PHP extension pack

What should be done in order to have MYSQL intellisense work properly?

Comment: try updating your VS Code it is working fine for me

Comment: and try downloading PHP Extension Pack by Felix Becker

Comment: @AhmedKhan, I have the latest version and I have PHP extension Pack by Felix Becker installed. Are you sure you have intellisense for mysqli_xxx and not for mysql_xxx only?

Comment: yes I am sure you can see here: [![Screenshot_3.png](https://s28.postimg.org/nwlgbpt2l/Screenshot_3.png)](https://postimg.org/image/m4shgt9pl/)

Comment: but they are not all

Comment: You do not have mysqli_query, right?

Comment: yeah they are not there.

Answer (score 9):

My most preferred extensions for PHP development in Visual Studio Code,

1. PHP Intelephense (Provides faster intellisense), [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client)
2. PHP CS Fixer (Formats PHP source files, including html files), [Visual Studio Market Place](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=junstyle.php-cs-fixer)
3. After installing these two extensions, go to visual studio code settings, and add below lines
   `"php.suggest.basic": false,
   "php-cs-fixer.formatHtml": true,`

   - As a side note, to enable php-cs-fixer format html embedded in php files, download this file and add the below settings to your visual studio code settings.
   - Php-cs-fixer.phar from [Github link](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer)

   `"php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "/path/to/php-cs-fixer.phar"`

Comment: Worked for me for mysqli_query but if you try to use something like example $conn_K->query() it will not find that way of doing it. Either way very helpful thanks.

Comment: Didn't know builtin PHP autocomplete was *so* basic. Builtin returns complete PHP dictionary of functions, superglobals and in-scope variables and types as object suggestions, context insensitive; disabling it with `php.suggest.basic: false` (and using Intelephense) made it more useful. Thanks.